# ExpressJs File upload Issue

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Even on uploading a file with .jpg or .png format it shows

> format not allowed, please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'.

I don't know why it is happening. How to solve or fix this issue? I tried to use ways suggested on some other websites to solve this issue but I wasn't able to fix this issue.

routes.js:

```
const {
   con,
   sessionStore
 } = require('./config/db');
exports.new = function(req, res){
    message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      const post  = req.body;
      const username= post.username;
      const title= post.title;
      const state= post.state;
      const category= post.category;
      const description= post.description;
 
      if (!req.files)
                return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
 
      const file = req.files.uploaded_image;
      var img_name=file.name;
 
         if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){
                                 
              file.mv('public/imgs/uploads/'+file.name, function(err) {
                             
               var sql = "INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `images` ,`description`) VALUES ?";
               var query = con.query(sql, [username, title, state, category, img_name, description], function(err) {
                 if (!err) {
                   res.redirect('show/' + username);
                 }
                 else {
                  message = "This format is not allowed , please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'";
                  res.render('new.ejs',{message: message});
                }
               }); 
            }); 
          
   } 
}
   else {
      res.render('new');
   }
 
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
    let message = '';
    var username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
      if(result.length <= 0)
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
   });
};
```

part of my new.ejs file

```
<form action="/" method="POST" role="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="was-validated">
        <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
          <div class="alert alert-success col-sm-12"><%= message %></div>
      <% } %>
      <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-lg">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">Username</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter Username" name="username">
        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
      </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-lg">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Title</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter Title" name="title">
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
  </div>


  <div class="custom-file mb-3">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="uploaded_image">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="uploaded_image">Choose file</label>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: show `err` content

Comment: as soon as I click the submit button after attaching a jpg or png file, it reloads the page and shows format not allowed, please upload a file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'. I would have shown you the error image as well but there is no option of attaching a pic here

Comment: just add `console.log(err)` before `if (!err) {` and add output to your post

Comment: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near ''user2'' at line 1

Comment: I suppose your INSERT statement should look like this `INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `images` ,`description`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use multer for image or file uploading to server. Because you must use buffer to transfer data from user to local or public server and must create session. You can do these using multer easily.

You can check

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Can you elaborate why using `multer` is fixing the issue ? Can you elaborate what you mean with `you must use buffer to transfer data to local or public server` and how that helps to fix this issue ?

Comment: I think you face the issue that req.files is undefined. The reason of this is file is not stored in bufffer, and you can not access to file. What I mean by that, the middleware will create a place for you to reach files, you will go that place to use files. This is why you must use multer or other frameworks.